# Insert 2 rows when a condition verified

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have a SELECT INTO #tTable SELECT CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 query.
When a particular condition is verified I have to insert into #tTable 2 rows instead of 1 that differ each other only for 1 column.

I resolved this problem in this way:

1. Insert into #tTable a foo row with value for my column v1v2
2. Insert into #tTable value1 where col = v1v2
3. Insert into #tTable value2 where col = v1v2
4. Delete from #tTable where col = v1v2

Is there a better and more performance way to do this? Is there a way to insert 2 rows in an INSERT INTO #table SELECT CASE WHEN statement?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO #tTable (col1, col2, col3)

SELECT T.col1, T.col2, CASE WHEN T.col1 > T.col2 THEN v1v2

WHEN T.col1 = T.col2 THEN value1 ELSE value2 END

FROM Table1 as T;

INSERT INTO #tTable (col1, col2, col3)

SELECT T.col1, T.col2, value1

FROM Table1 as T

WHERE T.col3 = v1v2;

INSERT INTO #tTable (col1, col2, col3)

SELECT T.col1, T.col2, value2

FROM Table1 as T

WHERE T.col3 = v1v2;

DELETE FROM #tTable

WHERE col3 = v1v2;
```

I have to insert 2 rows (one with value1 and other with value2) on case when T.col1 > T.col2

EDIT:

Actually, my query is like this:

```
INSERT INTO #tTable (col1, col2, col3)

SELECT T.col1, T.col2,

CASE WHEN condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 THEN value1

WHEN condition4 AND condition5 AND condition6 THEN value2

WHEN condition7 AND condition8 AND condition9 THEN v1v2 END

FROM Table1 as T
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here. That first statement isn't valid SQL, so showing your actual attempts will be useful as well.

Comment: Please read the first three paragraphs of the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Post your query also.

Comment: I can't post my real query, but this is my problem (question edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generate another row with a `CASE`, you will have to use `UNION ALL` or an additional `INSERT`. The simplest way I see it is with a `UNION ALL`, repeating the condition for `v1 + v2` on each `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO #tTable (
    col1, 
    col2, 
    col3)
SELECT
    V.Col1,
    V.Col2,
    col3 = V.value1
FROM
    Table1 AS V
WHERE
    (condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3) OR -- value1 condition
    (condition7 AND condition8 AND condition9) -- shared condition

UNION ALL

SELECT
    V.Col1,
    V.Col2,
    col3 = V.value2
FROM
    Table1 AS V
WHERE
    (condition4 AND condition5 AND condition6) OR -- value2 condition
    (condition7 AND condition8 AND condition9) -- shared condition
```

If your conditions are bound to change or are complex, you can write them only once if you place them on a CTE and reference their output:

```
;WITH DataWithConditions AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Col1,
        T.Col2,
        T.Value1,
        T.Value2,
        Condition = CASE
            WHEN condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 THEN 1
            WHEN condition4 AND condition5 AND condition6 THEN 2
            WHEN condition7 AND condition8 AND condition9 THEN 3 END
    FROM
        Table1 AS T
)
INSERT INTO #tTable (
    col1, 
    col2, 
    col3)
SELECT
    V.Col1,
    V.Col2,
    col3 = V.value1
FROM
    DataWithConditions AS V
WHERE
    V.Condition IN (1, 3)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    V.Col1,
    V.Col2,
    col3 = V.value2
FROM
    DataWithConditions AS V
WHERE
    V.Condition IN (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try UNION ALL to incorporate the second column's value as ROW as shown below-

```
INSERT INTO #tTable (col1, col2, col3)

SELECT T.col1, T.col2,
       CASE
           WHEN T.col1 > T.col2 THEN value1 -- Column name may be v1v2
           WHEN T.col1 = T.col2 THEN value1
           ELSE value2
       END
FROM Table1 AS T

UNION ALL

SELECT T.col1, T.col2,value2 -- Value2 I guess the 2nd column
FROM Table1 AS T WHERE  T.col1 > T.col2
```

Comment: I simplified too much my query. I edited the question with a more real one

Comment: Please put some sample date from your source table including logic/case when to insert which data. This will help.

Comment: I cannot disclose data as it is sensitive data. The conditions are similar to:
col1 = 'string'
col1 <> 'string'
col1 is not null
col1 is null

Comment: Use dummy data rather than real one.